# PostgreSQL: Parallel Workers Error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, memory, parallelism, max-connections

For the last two days one of our query causing parallel workers related errors as below,

```
2024-01-04 13:58:45.988 CST,"user_a","testdb",108428,"10.0.0.1:46480",6596490c.1a78c,150,"SELECT",2024-01-04 13:58:36 CST,398/8937486,0,ERROR,53300,"remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections",,,,,"parallel worker","SELECT count(*) AS ""count"" FROM ""view_a"" AS ""vi_a"" WHERE ""vi_a"".""status"" = 1 AND ""vi_a"".""id"" IN (select ab_id from tab1 where status=2 group by ab_id);",,,"","client backend"
2024-01-04 13:58:45.989 CST,,,108647,,65964915.1a867,1,,2024-01-04 13:58:45 CST,,0,ERROR,55000,"could not map dynamic shared memory segment",,,,,,,,,"","parallel worker"
2024-01-04 13:58:45.990 CST,,,88206,,62b0ea26.1588e,17270,,2022-06-21 05:44:06 CST,,0,LOG,00000,"background worker ""parallel worker"" (PID 108646) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster"
```

`SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "view_a" AS "vi_a" WHERE "vi_a"."status" = 1 AND "vi_a"."id" IN (select ab_id from tab1 where status=2 group by ab_id)`

I have checked the execution plan of this query but only take 180-200ms with two parallel workers. I have tried the same query by disabling parallelism still the same execution time. Can it be something wrong with the query? OR

Is this something related to `max_parallel_workers` as it running out of parallel workers?

Comment: Your log messages seem to have been mutilated, which makes it hard to figure out how they relate to each other.  What is your logging configuration?  Also, what is your version, and what is the query being run (simplify it if you want, but then make sure the simplified version still displays the same problem).  Are any of the table foreign tables?

Comment: @jjanes i hv updated the log with query. We are running on PostgreSQL13

Comment: Are you running v13.13, or some earlier minor version?  I don't see why the error reported by the parallel worker itself would be different than the one reported by the client backend on behalf of the parallel worker.  But maybe there are multiple errors occurring across the system at the same time and those two errors are not otherwise related to each other.  Maybe there is a bug where the message get overwritten.  Looking at the error reported by the parallel worker itself, it can't attach to the shared memory segment.  That suggests something going on in the OS/kernel.

Comment: Our system were hitting connection limit sometimes and after resolving that issue this error no more generated.